# Tangible alternative to paper U.S. savings bonds?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds, cash, gifts, paper-money

When I was little, it was fairly common to get US Savings Bonds from relatives. It introduced me to savings, financial instruments, and the idea of delayed gratification. I know there are 529 plans, [a rather cumbersome "replacement" method via treasurydirect.gov](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/planning/plan_gifts.htm), and other arduous methods (trusts, custodial accounts, etc).

[In 2012, the US Treasury stopped issuing paper bonds](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/news/pressroom/pressroom_comotcend0711.htm). Before that, you could go into most banks and simply buy a savings bond in someone else's name, hand it to them with their birthday card, and that was that.

**Is there any type of bond (or similar instrument), held as paper, and redeemed rather simply?** Buying a tangible and appreciating investment seems so much better than some cash or consumer gift card. I'm aware of [the risks to things like bearer bonds](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/bonds/08/bearer-bond.asp), but I think in my case the issue is moot. Any physical asset would share the same risks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use your tax refund to buy them, you can still get paper I bonds.

https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ibonds/res_ibonds_ibuy.htm

Also look for form 8888 from www.irs.gov.